# tikzpicture as section title but text in table of contents

Tags: tikz-pgf, table-of-contents, sectioning

I want to use a little banner as title in \section. It should look like the banner above "vocabulaire" but the text doesn't change its size and I would like to get rid of the section numbering. My second problem is that I want the banner to appear in the body of the document but not in the table of contents. Is it possible to have only the date there?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, text={16.5cm, 25.2cm}, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols,shadows}

\definecolor{bancolor}{RGB}{62,96,111}


 \DeclareRobustCommand\datebanner[2]{\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[
  signal,
  signal from=north,
  signal pointer angle=150,
  fill=bancolor!75,
  drop shadow={shadow xshift=0pt, color=bancolor},
  rotate=-90,
  text width=2cm,
  text height=1.5cm,
  anchor=north west
  ] (banner) at (0,0) {};
% the text in the banner
\node[
  anchor=south,
  text width=3cm,
  align=center,
  font=\itshape] 
  at ([yshift=1cm]banner.east) {#1 \\ #2};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{\datebanner{2. April}{2018}}


\vspace{64pt}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[
  signal,
  signal from=north,
  signal pointer angle=150,
  fill=bancolor!75,
  drop shadow={shadow xshift=0pt, color=bancolor},
  rotate=-90,
  text width=2cm,
  text height=1.5cm,
  anchor=north west
  ] (banner) at (0,0) {};
% the text in the banner
\node[
  anchor=south,
  text width=3cm,
  align=center,
  font=\itshape] 
  at ([yshift=1cm]banner.east) {28. April \\ 2018};
\end{tikzpicture}

\subsection{Vocabulaire}

\subsection{film}


\subsection{grammaire}

\subsubsection{Si + ...}

\subsection{orthographie}

\end{document}
```

So far it looks like this

[image]

Comment: Are all `\section`s like this? I.e., do you want to hide the numbering of all the `\section`s? For the second part, `\section[2. April 2018]{\datebanner{2. April}{2018}}`. The optional argument to `\section` is used to define an alternative text for the ToC.

Comment: Thank you, that solved the ToC problem. Yes all \section are like this. How do I prevent the text in the banner to change it size?

Comment: So no section number in the text. Next question: should there be a section number in the table of contents? Next piece of the puzzle: you can replace `font=\itshape` with  `font=\normalsize\itshape` to overwrite the font size set by `\section`.

Comment: Yes, section number should be in the table of contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses the `titlesec` package to format the section title. The font is set to the default in `\titleformat` (second argument), which is overwritten with `font=` in the `tikzpicture`. Otherwise, the title of the table of contents would be in italic too. The fourth argument sets the distance between the label and the title. Since the label, i.e. the section number, is left empty (fourth argument), `0pt` puts the banner at the left.

I also took the freedom to improve your banner command a bit. Using `minimum width` instead of `text width` ensures, that the banner adapts to the text, if it is wider.

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, text={16.5cm, 25.2cm}, centering]{geometry}
%\usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

%added
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}{}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols,shadows}

\definecolor{bancolor}{RGB}{62,96,111}

% changed, only one argument now
\DeclareRobustCommand\datebanner[1]{\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[
  signal,
  signal to=south,
  signal pointer angle=150,
  fill=bancolor!75,
  drop shadow={shadow xshift=0pt, color=bancolor},
  minimum width=2.5cm,
  minimum height=3cm,
  align=center,
  font=\normalsize\itshape
  ] (banner) at (0,0) {#1};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section[1. Mai 2018]{\datebanner{1. Mai\\2018}}

\section[2. April 2018]{\datebanner{2. April\\2018}}

\section[27. September 2018]{\datebanner{27. September\\2018}}


\subsection{Vocabulaire}

\subsection{film}


\subsection{grammaire}

\subsubsection{Si + ...}

%\subsection{orthographie}

\end{document}
```